# what does Destiny Profile Collectible state 3 and 5 means - Bungie API

Tags: api

I am working on Bungie API and want to know what does 3, 5, 9, 13, 65 and 69 state for Destiny Collectible means?
I was not able to find 3, 5, 9, 13, 65 and 69 on [Official Bungie API Documentation Page](https://bungie-net.github.io/#/components/schemas/Destiny.DestinyCollectibleState).
It only have 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 and 64 as State enum.

May be i am Looking at wrong place.

URL: `https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/{membershiptype}/Profile/{destinyMembershipid}/?components=100,102,103,104,200,201,202,204,205,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,800,900,1100`

I am getting values from this : `Response.profileCollectibles.data.collectibles`

Any Help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the docs, the returned `state` value is a bitmask. A bitmask is essentially a number that acts as booleans using the binary representation of the number. For example, the number 5 in binary is `0101` and implies that out of 4 booleans (aka flags) represented by this number, the second and final booleans/flags are true, with the first and third being false. This is by no means an excellent explanation on what a bitmask is, and I'm sure there are many questions pertaining to bitmasks on StackOverflow - have a quick Google search if you're still lost.

To add context to this response, here are the values used, their binary representation, and their definition ([Bungie.NET API](https://bungie-net.github.io/multi/schema_Destiny-DestinyCollectibleState.html#schema_Destiny-DestinyCollectibleState)):

```
 1 - 000 0001 - Not yet acquired/collected
 2 - 000 0010 - Obscured (Use a different hash to display this collectible)
 4 - 000 0100 - Invisible and should not be shown to the user
 8 - 000 1000 - User cannot afford to recreate this collectible
16 - 001 0000 - User doesn't have the inventory space to create this collectible
32 - 010 0000 - The user already has this collectible, and cannot create a second one
64 - 100 0000 - Creating this collectible has been disabled (for whatever reason)
```

Using the knowledge of how a bitmask works, we can now derive the meaning of a state not found in this list. To do this, we need to convert our state into a binary representation and determine which "flags" are active.

So for state 13, we can represent this as `000 1101`. Let's break this down referencing our table:

```
000 1101 - 13 is our returned state!
--------
000 0001 - The collectible hasn't be acquired yet
000 0100 - The collectible is invisible and should not be shown to the user
000 1000 - The collectible is too expensive for the user
```

You can test for these flags in your application using the **bitwise AND** operation (typically denoted as a single `&`). Ie:

```js
let state = 13; // 0b0001101 - Taken from the response JSON
let invisible = 4; // 0b0000100 - You'd probably have this as a global constant
if(state & invisible == invisible) hideThisItemFromPlayer();
```

Like I said above, you might want to Google more about bitmasks to understand them in-depth, but this run down should give you an idea.